# missing android service though properly declared in code and manifest

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-manifest

I get an error as if the LocationService i'm using cannot be found
what am i missing?

[image]

here is my manifest:

```
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.StoresListActivity" >
                        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService" />
```

my StoresListActivity class:

```
package com.example.manyexampleapp;

public class StoresListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LocationService locService = new LocationService();

        locService.startService(new Intent());
    }
```

my LocationService class

```
package com.example.manyexampleapp;

public class LocationService extends Service {
public static final String LOCATION_BROAD_MSG = "Hello World";
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

public LocationManager locationManager;
public MyLocationListener listener;
public Location previousBestLocation = null;

Intent intent;
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    intent = new Intent(LOCATION_BROAD_MSG);      
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new MyLocationListener();        
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 0, listener);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start a service like this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      Intent intent=new Intent("com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService");  
      this.startService(intent);
}
```

And mention required permission in your Android manifest file i.e.

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Permission) is details.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your service that way:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For start Service use this

```
 startService(new Intent(this, LocationService.class));
```

Instead of

```
 LocationService locService = new LocationService();

 locService.startService(new Intent());
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your intent object in StoresListActivity. ,ie,

`locService.startService(new Intent());`

Trigger your service like this :

```
Intent i= new Intent(context, CustomService.class);

context.startService(i);
```